# Very slow update of global variables - python

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have made a node which takes input from several different sensors. I want to proces the sensor data and publish a on a new topic.

However when I move the data from the callback functions to my processing algorithm the using global variables, the variables are updated very slowly.

I have a very simplified node of what I have done...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan
from std_msgs.msg import Float64

ranges = []

def callback(data):
     global ranges
     rospy.loginfo(data)
     ranges = data.ranges[200]
def listener():
     rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
     rospy.Subscriber("scan", LaserScan, callback)      
if __name__ == '__main__':
      while not rospy.is_shutdown():
           listener()
           rospy.Publisher('talk', Float64, queue_size=5).publish(ranges)
           rospy.sleep(0.01)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221981/very-slow-update-of-global-variables---python/) by [Oevli](https://answers.ros.org/users/25151/oevli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2015-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> if __name__ == '__main__':
> ```

```
      while not rospy.is_shutdown():
           listener()
           rospy.Publisher('talk', Float64, queue_size=5).publish(ranges)
           rospy.sleep(0.01)
```

You are re-creating your subscriber every `0.01` seconds, which is probably not what you want.

> However when I move the data from the callback functions to my processing algorithm the using global variables, the variables are updated very slowly.

I can imagine that the chances of ROS successfully registering your subscriber, receiving a message *and* delivering it to your callback in `0.01` sec are rather slim, and only succeeds every now and then. If that leads to most messages being missed, it would appear as if updates to `ranges` are very slow. In reality, they are probably very infrequent.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2